# I can see message in DLQ logs, Where can I see messages published to Amazon SNS Topic?

Tags: amazon-sns

I can see message in DLQ logs, Where can I see messages published to Amazon SNS Topic?
I would like to compare good message and message ended up in DLQ
I am looking for reason why it ended up in DLQ